# How to resize bootstrap <div class="container"> after adding some html code into the page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

Below is my intial webpage code.

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-left quiz-container">
  <div id="quiz" class="container"></div>
</div>
```

This code gets changed to the below code when I run the webpage as I add this using javascript

```
<div class="row d-flex align-items-left justify-content-left quiz-container">
   <div class="container" id="quiz">
      <div class="slide active-slide">
         <div class="question">
            <p style="line-height:1.3"> Who invented JavaScript? </p>
         </div>
         <div class="answers">
            <label>
               <div class="choice-container">
                  <input type="radio" name="question0" value="A">
                  <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
                  <p class="choice-text">Douglas Crockford</p>
               </div>
            </label>
            <label>
               <div class="choice-container">
                  <input type="radio" name="question0" value="B">
                  <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
                  <p class="choice-text">Sheryl Sandberg</p>
               </div>
            </label>
            <label>
               <div class="choice-container">
                  <input type="radio" name="question0" value="C">
                  <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
                  <p class="choice-text">Brendan Eich</p>
               </div>
            </label>
            <label>
               <div class="choice-container">
                  <input type="radio" name="question0" value="D">
                  <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
                  <p class="choice-text">KJ Munro</p>
               </div>
            </label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

There are multiple (div class="slide") inside the "quiz" division. I want to change the height of quiz division depending on the size of active slide

Comment: if position is not set, then the container will take the space as per quiz. Are you using any styles to change the quiz layout ? What's your current output and expected output ? Need more clear details